# Select de Native Base que me permite escribir cuando no deberia

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, librería

Estoy utilizando Native Base y me cruzo con un Dropdown (Select) el cual por alguna extraña razón me permite escribir en el campo...
Por ejemplo cuando yo quiero apretar para mostrar el listado sucede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la screenshot, me muestra un " | " el cual significa que puedo escribir y sumado a eso me abre el teclado... Pero al apretar el icon del lado derecho me lo muestra correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuestión que me fije la documentación y no encuentro nada relacionado a esto, es bastante extraño...
La idea es que al apretar tanto en el icon como en el campo me permita seleccionar como en la ultima Screenshot, no que me permita escribir debido a que no es un input si no un select.

Este es mi select:

```
<Select
                                    selectedValue={especialidad}
                                    accessibilityLabel="Dirección"
                                    placeholder="Dirección"
                                    _selectedItem={{
                                        bg: "teal.600"
                                    }}
                                    onValueChange={itemValue => setProvincia(itemValue)}
                                >
                                      {provinciaSelect.map((provincia, index) => (
                                    <Select.Item label={provincia.nombre} value={provincia.id} key={index}/>
                                ))}
                                </Select>
```